# How to include multiple spaces in TextView？

Tags: sapui5

It seems that the text for TextView cannot accept multiple spaces. Multiple spaces will be trimmed down to one. 
**new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text: "abccd         sadf"});**
is the same as 
**new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text: "abccd sadf"});**
and '\t' is also the same as ' '. 
But what if I want to represent multiple spaces or '\t' in a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\u0020` or `\u00a0` to include multiple spaces.

```
new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
    text: "\u0020"
});
new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
    text: "\u00a0"
});
```

`\u0020` is a "normal" space, `\u00a0` is the non-breaking-space (HTML's `&nbsp;`)

or for your case:

```
new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
    text: "abccd\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020sadf"
});
```

Comment: "\u00a0" did solve same for sap.m.MessagePopover item description text (sap.m.MessagePopoverItem, 'description')

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use formatter function for this type of scenarios.